Anaconda Build Channels
In the following requirements.txt, what does the addition non-pypi syntax mean? My MRE is what the package author suggests, installing this with conda create --name multid_features --file requirements.txt with no other instructions, so I suspect there is some knowledge about conda that would allow me to install it.
_libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
_openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
absl-py=2.1.0=pypi_0
accelerate=0.27.2=pypi_0
adjusttext=1.1.1=pypi_0
...

In normal python, the format is "name=version". Here, there's a name after every package. How do you install e.g. certifi=2024.2.2=py311h06a4308_0?
Conda cannot find any of the packages:
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - zstd==1.5.5=hc292b87_0
  - zstandard==0.22.0=pypi_0
  - zlib==1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
  ...

Do you need to add a channel? What do you do?

I can reproduce the failure on a linux-64 system. I'm not sure how to handle this, I suggest getting in touch with the author of the repo to see what they suggest.

Ok, probably the correct way to handle this is to look at the build strings and determine what they mean, and then add the channels associated with those build strings. Where can I find out what the build strings mean? Every question on stackoverflow explains the build strings only for build strings that start with "py[version]..."

The file that you are quoting was created using conda env export and there are two types of information present:

hc292b87_0 - like strings: Those are, as you say, build strings. Quoting from the conda documentation:


An arbitrary string that identifies a particular build of a package for conda. It may contain suggestive mnemonics, but these are subject to change, and you should not rely on it or try to parse it for any specific information.

There is no meaning to them. When exporting environment, they are a very strict limitation to which exact package built was present. This string is different between versions for different OS and can also change in case maintainers decide to recompile and repackage a version at a later point.

=pypi_0 like strings: these indicate that the package was installed using pip.

Note
By now, the requirements.txt file on the website has been "fixed"
